# Upgrading from GCC 4.8.2 to GCC 4.9.0 without a complete rebuild

Tags: gcc, gcc4.8, gcc4.9

I installed the GCC 4.8.2 a couple of weeks ago. The installation process went well and I have GCC 4.8.2 at my Ubuntu system (12.04 64 bits). Now GNU just released the newer version 4.9.0.

My question is: Is there any way to upgrade my GCC to 4.9.0 without doing all process: configuration, building, checking and installation from scratch?
Also, please tell me what is the benefit/purpose of gcc-4.8.2-4.9.0.diff.gz file?
Is it like script/patch file to upgrade my compiler?

FYI, I don't have any plan to have two different versions of GCC at my system.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software.

Comment: I guess it should be moved to Unix&Linux SX site. Who is able to do this?

Comment: It isn't too Off-topic! Actually it's about installing/upgrading GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: Is there any way to upgrade my GCC to 4.9.0 without doing all process: configuration, building, checking and installation from scratch?

Yes, if you have it already built. No, if you have only sources.

> Also, please tell me what is the benefit/purpose of gcc-4.8.2-4.9.0.diff.gz file?

Read manual for `patch` utility how to apply it. You can convert 4.8.2 sources to 4.9.0 ones with this diff.

> Is it like script/patch file to upgrade my compiler?

Yes, but for its sources. So building is still required.

Do you really need new features of 4.9 for your projects?

Comment: Netch, May I ask you explain more? I have a GCC 4.8.2 build from source and currently I have the source of 4.9.0.

Comment: Apply `patch` to source directory with the diff file you've got and remake the building process from the very beginning.

Comment: Netch, In response to your question about Do I really need new features of 4.9, I should say, I'm a C++ Programmer and an advisory member of C++ committee from IRAN and I follow the new features of C++ (C++14) which were added to C++ recently. Also, I present seminars in IRAN/Tehran about C++, so I should have most recent GCC/Clang/Visual Studio compilers permanently.

Comment: Ok, got it. In that case I guess you need both compilers in parallel to compare their work, so I suggest configuring them with different prefixes (like `/opt/gcc-4.9.0`) and not overwrite older one with the newer one.

Comment: Netch, May I ask you explain (the UNIX command) how to apply a diff file on a source directory?

Comment: `patch -d $directory <$diff_file`, in most cases. But, depending on diff style, some other options can be needed. Very often, one shall specify `-p$level` to drop directories from patch paths.